# How to visualize a C-band SAR sensor measurement

Tags: raster, radar, sentinel-1

```
Files: \measurement\s1a-iw2-slc-vv-20141205t171642-20141205t171705-003587-0043c5-002.tiff
Size is 24435, 13472
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2014:12:05 21:24:05
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=Sentinel-1A IW SLC L1
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=Sentinel-1 IPF 002.36
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,13472.0)
Upper Right (24435.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (24435.0,13472.0)
Center      (12217.5, 6736.0)
Band 1 Block=24435x1 Type=CInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Its from teh sentinel 1 sat, and I am wondering about what the steps are to visualize this in somethign that makes sense to normal people. In the download, there is a preview image that makes sense, but I dont know how to create that myself.

Comment: Can you add from where you download the data?

Comment: Sentinel 1 scientific data hub: https://scihub.esa.int/

Comment: See the software guide at https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-1-sar